# Is there a numpy method to determine if one array or matrix is a translation of another

Tags: python, numpy

What is the correct/fastest way to determine if one numpy matrix is a simple translation of another?  For example these two matrices:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],
             [1,3],
             [2,4]])

b = a + np.array([1,4])
```

The function should return True, where it would be False for say

```
c = np.array([[1,5],
             [1,3],
             [2,4]])
```

I've been thinking of a function like this:

```
def check_translation(m1,m2):
    m10 = m1 - m1[0,:]
    m20 = m2 - m2[0,:]
    
    if np.all(m10==m20):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Which gives:

```
check_translation(a,b)
True

check_translation(a,c)
False
```

But was hoping there could be a more direct method using numpy

Comment: What exactly do you mean with translation? For example, your code says  `check_translation(a, a+a)` is `False`.

Comment: Or `check_translation(a, a + np.array([[1, 2, 3]]).T)`, also returns `False`.

Comment: I was thinking check if one set of points is a fixed shift of another set, so translation like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)

Comment: Yes but what is the meaning of your matrix, how does it represent the "set of points"? Each row represents one point?

Comment: Yes, that's right, sorry that wasn't clear!  I have an algorithm producing candidate sets of points and I want to eliminate those which are just a translation of another one to get down to unique candidates

Comment: For that larger goal, do you intend to check every pair of candidate sets? If so, that seems inefficient. Might want to make that another question so we can suggest something better there :-)

Answer (score 2):

Computing all individual point translations and checking that they're all the same:

```
def check_translation(m1, m2):
    d = m1 - m2
    return (d == d[0]).all()
```

That returns a `numpy.bool_`. If you need a Python `bool`:

```
def check_translation(m1, m2):
    d = m1 - m2
    return bool((d == d[0]).all())
```